# Find Largest subarray( descending order)in a list of array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to find the largest subarray. For example: array list `{ 1, 4, 7, 3, -3, -4, -1, 4, 2, 1 }` need to find the largest subarray where the numbers are decreasing.

As from the list `{ 7, 3, -3, -4 }` is one subarray and `{ 4, 2, 1 }`, as the earlier one is biggest need to print that.

Comment: define biggest... longest, or with the greatest differential? Anyway just use 2 for loops and keep the results of the largest found to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
var results = new List<int>();

for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{

   // how we check
   var current = new List<int>();

   // just to know if we are are going down
   var lastValue = input[i];

   // second loop make sure we stop if the numbers aren't going down
   for (var j = i; j < input.Length && input[j] <= lastValue; j++)
   {
      current.Add(input[j]);
      lastValue = input[j];
   }
   // Update the result depending on the criteria 
   if (current.Count >= results.Count)
   {
      results = current;
   }
}

// print your awesome numbers
foreach (var value in results)
{
   Console.Write($"{value}, ");
}
```

[You can test it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6cEBFm)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Fresher if this has answered your question feel free to upvote and mark it as correct making it more visible to other users, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this LINQ approach:

```
var array = new[] { 1, 4, 7, 3, -3, -4, -1, 4, 2, 1 };

var descending_subarrays =
    array
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(new [] { array.Take(1).ToList() }.ToList(), (a, x) =>
        {
            if (a.Last().Last() > x)
            {
                a.Last().Add(x);
            }
            else
            {
                a.Add(new [] { x }.ToList());
            }
            return a;
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
        .ToList();
```

That gives:

[image: result]

You can then just pick the find answer with a `descending_subarrays.First()`.